# Formatting rows in a datagrid to look blank

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, datagrid

Essentially, I am using a datagrid in WPF.  If there is a row that contains no data, I want it to be a blank row and I want it to display as below:

[image]

However I am having real trouble trying to achieve this.  I can do it by creating separate datagrids and splitting the data into each with a converter but it becomes very messy and makes the code hard to maintain.

I can also do it by leaving the row blank which looks as below:

[image]

However that does not look quite how I would like.  Any help is appreciated and thanks in advance.

Code for the datagrid:

```
<DataGrid Width="265" RowHeight="11.5" CanUserAddRows="False"  ItemsSource="{Binding Coupon.SelectionAreas[0].SelectionRows
                                ,Converter={StaticResource DateTimeToSplitDataGridConverter}
                                ,ConverterParameter='Table13Bet'}" AutoGenerateColumns="False" Background="Transparent"  RowBackground="Transparent" HeadersVisibility="None" BorderBrush="LightGray" BorderThickness="1,0,1,0" AlternatingRowBackground="{x:Null}" GridLinesVisibility="Horizontal" IsReadOnly="True" SelectionMode="Single" >
                        <DataGrid.Columns>
                            <DataGridTemplateColumn Width="27">
                                <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate  >
                                    <DataTemplate DataType="r:SelectionRow">
                                        <TextBlock  Text="{Binding ExpectedOffDate,StringFormat='HH:mm'}" VerticalAlignment="Top" FontFamily="Arial Narrow" FontSize="7.8" HorizontalAlignment="Center" Foreground="{Binding Path=ColourForeground, Converter={StaticResource HexToForegroundColourConverter}}" 
                                       Background="{Binding Path=ColourBackground, Converter={StaticResource HexToBackgroundColourConverter}}" />
                                    </DataTemplate>
                                </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                            </DataGridTemplateColumn>
                            <DataGridTemplateColumn Width="27" >
                                <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                                    <DataTemplate DataType="r:SelectionRow">
                                        <TextBlock  Text="{Binding SelectionHome.Odd, Converter={StaticResource ChangeZeroToOneOddsToTbcConverter}}" FontFamily="Arial Narrow" VerticalAlignment="Top" FontSize="7.8" HorizontalAlignment="Center" Background="{Binding Path=ColourBackground, Converter={StaticResource HexToBackgroundColourConverter}}" />
                                    </DataTemplate>
                                </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                            </DataGridTemplateColumn>

                            <DataGridTemplateColumn Width="80" >
                                <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                                    <DataTemplate DataType="r:SelectionRow">
                                        <TextBlock Text="{Binding SelectionHome.DisplayName, Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" VerticalAlignment="Top" FontFamily="Arial Narrow" FontSize="7.8" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Background="{Binding Path=ColourBackground, Converter={StaticResource HexToBackgroundColourConverter}}" />
                                    </DataTemplate>
                                </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                            </DataGridTemplateColumn>


                            <DataGridTemplateColumn Width="24">
                                <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                                    <DataTemplate DataType="r:SelectionRow">
                                        <TextBlock  Text="{Binding SelectionDraw.Odd, Converter={StaticResource ChangeZeroToOneOddsToTbcConverter}}" VerticalAlignment="Top" FontFamily="Arial Narrow" FontSize="7.8" HorizontalAlignment="Center" Background="{Binding Path=ColourBackground, Converter={StaticResource HexToBackgroundColourConverter}}" />
                                    </DataTemplate>
                                </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                            </DataGridTemplateColumn>

                            <DataGridTemplateColumn Width="80" >
                                <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                                    <DataTemplate DataType="r:SelectionRow">
                                        <TextBlock  Text="{Binding SelectionAway.DisplayName, Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" VerticalAlignment="Top" FontFamily="Arial Narrow" FontSize="7.8" HorizontalAlignment="Right" Background="{Binding Path=ColourBackground, Converter={StaticResource HexToBackgroundColourConverter}}" />
                                    </DataTemplate>
                                </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                            </DataGridTemplateColumn>

                            <DataGridTemplateColumn Width="25" >
                                <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                                    <DataTemplate DataType="r:SelectionRow">
                                        <TextBlock  Text="{Binding SelectionAway.Odd, Converter={StaticResource ChangeZeroToOneOddsToTbcConverter}}" VerticalAlignment="Top" FontFamily="Arial Narrow" FontSize="7.8" HorizontalAlignment="Center" Background="{Binding Path=ColourBackground, Converter={StaticResource HexToBackgroundColourConverter}}" />
                                    </DataTemplate>
                                </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                            </DataGridTemplateColumn>

                        </DataGrid.Columns>
                    </DataGrid>
```

Comment: Could you show us the relevant code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

it is possible to display empty `RowDetails` under certain rows

```
<DataGrid>
    <DataGrid.RowDetailsTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <Grid Height="20"/>
        </DataTemplate>
    </DataGrid.RowDetailsTemplate>

    <DataGrid.RowStyle>
        <Style TargetType="DataGridRow">
            <Setter Property="DetailsVisibility" 
                    Value="{Binding Path=ShowEmptyRow, 
                                    Converter={StaticResource BoolToVisible}}"/>
        </Style>
    </DataGrid.RowStyle>
<DataGrid>
```

`ShowEmptyRow` is some `bool` property which indicates that there should be an empty space under current DataGridRow

Comment: I've had a go with what you have suggested but the problem I've ran into is I cant set the showEmptyRow binding to take in each individual row, its asking for something similar to my ItemSource.  I cant see a way of setting the dataType as I've done in the Cell templates either.  Is there away around this?

Comment: I got it working, seems it works at run time alright just in design time it was being funny.  Thanks